# create array from associative array with two keys snf and rate where snf unique with its related rate in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**I have an associative array given below:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.000
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [47] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [48] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [49] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [53] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [54] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [55] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [56] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [57] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [58] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [59] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [60] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )

    [61] => Array
        (
            [Snf] => 2.100
            [Rate] => 0.000
        )
```

**And i want result array as per given below:**

```
    Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [Snf] => 2.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
    )
    [1] => array(
        [Snf] => 2.100
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
        [Rate] => 0.000
    )
)
```

Comment: @Ruslan Osmanov Thankyou for editing :)

Comment: Is the value of `Rate` always 0.000? If yes, you just have to count the amounts of `Snf` to get the amount of `Rate = 0.000`

Comment: no it should be changed accordingly.

Comment: Question??? You cannot use duplicate array indices??? you can turn [rate] => 0.000 into array instead... [rate] => array(0.000, 0.000) what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes this should also work for me @Hallur array like [0] => array(
        [Snf] => 2.000
        [Rate] => array(0.000,0.000)
)

Comment: @MilanSoni can you change the input array? It would be a lot easier to change the structure from the input array, than having to iterate through it complexly to get the wanted output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention on your code, you can not keep same key (Rate) multiple time within an array. Therefore you can do that this way,

example:

```
array('Snf'=>2.00, 'Rate'=>array(0.00, 0.00, 0.00))
```

You can get above output using following code. `$data` represent your existing array,

```
$Snf = "";
$output = array();
$key = 0;
foreach($data as $item=>$rate){
    if($rate['Snf'] != $Snf){
        if($item != 0){
            $key++;
        }
        $output[$key]['Snf'] =  $rate['Snf'];
        $keyRate = 0;
    }
    $output[$key]['Rate'][$keyRate] = $rate['Rate'];
    $Snf = $rate['Snf'];
    $keyRate++;
}
// print the output
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```